# Image absolute position linked to a url

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place an image in an absolute position on the page and then link the image to an external url. The image absolute position works fine. But the link doesn't appear when I hover over the image or click it. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

This is my Code:

```css
.front-page-img1 img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 340px;
  margin-left: -30px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="front-page-img1">
  <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com">
    <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/500/500">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You're moving only the image, not the anchor (which stays in place). A click on the image should still trigger the link, though. Since you make the image absolute positioned, the anchor no longer has any content that would cause it to have non-zero dimensions, so it becomes 0px * 0px.

Comment: Can you provide more info? I ran your code in a fiddle and got the desired effect. https://jsfiddle.net/phovp8n9/

Comment: create a fiddle with your whole code...it gives more context...your code works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

You are moving just the image not the anchor tag ,so that's why when you hover on image ,you are just hovering on image not on the anchor tag ,so that's the reason changes of hover are not effected

move the whole div not just the image ,then you can see the change

check the snippet

```css
.front-page-img1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 140px;
  margin-left: -30px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
a {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.front-page-img1 a:hover {
  border: 20px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="front-page-img1">
  <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/500/500">
  </a>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You're moving only the image, not the anchor (which stays in place). A click on the image should still trigger the link, though.

Because you make the image absolute positioned, it is completely removed from the document flow and the `a`no longer has any content that would cause it to have non-zero dimensions, so it becomes 0px * 0px:

[image]